# MySQL database composite fk design consideration

Tags: mysql, database-design

First, this is my first post here but for years this site has been "the place" when I need my questions answered. However I stumpled on a MySQL database desgin issue I can't seem to find an answer to or resolve myself.

A code snippet of the involved tables is posted here (Workbench generated). Question comes after

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestCenter`.`test` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_number` VARCHAR(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(YEAR(create_time), '-',  seq_number)) VIRTUAL,
  `seq_number` INT(5) ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
  `test_state_id` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `customer_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `sample_rate` INT NOT NULL,
  `comment` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `create_time` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `start_time` DATETIME NULL,
  `end_time` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_idx_test_customer_id` (`customer_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_idx_test_test_state_id` (`test_state_id` ASC),
  INDEX `idx_test_start_and_end_time` (`start_time` ASC, `end_time` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `report_number_UNIQUE` (`report_number` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_customer_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`customer` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_test_state_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`test_state_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`test_state` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestCenter`.`machine` (
  `id` TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `is_controlled` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestCenter`.`motion` (
  `id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `plc_value` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestCenter`.`machine_motion` (
  `machine_id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `motion_id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  INDEX `fk_idx_machine_motion_motion_id` (`motion_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`machine_id`, `motion_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_machine_motion_machine_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`machine_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`machine` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_machine_motion_motion_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`motion_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`motion` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestCenter`.`test_step` (
  `step_number` INT NOT NULL,
  `test_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `machine_id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `motion_id` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `step_state_id` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `auto_continue` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `start_time` DATETIME NULL,
  `end_time` DATETIME NULL,
  INDEX `fk_idx_test_step_machine_and motion_id` (`machine_id` ASC, `motion_id` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`, `step_number`),
  INDEX `fk_idx_test_step_step_state_id` (`step_state_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_idx_test_step_test_id` (`test_id` ASC, `machine_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_step_machine_and motion_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`machine_id` , `motion_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`machine_motion` (`machine_id` , `motion_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_step_test_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`test` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_test_step_step_state_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`step_state_id`)
    REFERENCES `TestCenter`.`test_state` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

And an image of the same tables from EER diagram [Image of involved tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB6Wj.png)

My problem is the 'machine_id' in the 'test_step' table (see image), which really doesn't belong there and should be in the 'test' table as a single test is done by the same machine regardless of how many steps is involved making the test. However I also want to have the fk constraint in the 'test_step' table only allowing valid 'machine_motion' combinations.

As I see it, one solution would be, have the 'machine_id' in the 'test' table aswell, but that would introduce a circular reference as the 'test' table would then reference the 'machine' table.

Another solution would be, remove the fk constraint from the 'test_step' table, move the 'machine_id' to the 'test' table and add a fk constraint to the 'motion_id' in the 'test_step' table referencing the 'motion' table.

Actually, while writing this I find that solution 2 might be the way to go but,

Am I missing something? Would really appreciate some input as I've been struggeling with this a few days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the existing design:

- *Each test may have more than one test steps; each test step belongs to exactly one test.*
- *Each test may be performed by more than one machine.*

So, whoever designed this, expected that more than one machine may participate in a single test. This may have been the requirement at the time.

Your statement

> ... single test is done by the same machine ..

changes that, and **introduces constraints** that can be verbalised as:

- *Each test is done by exactly one machine, for each machine it is possible that more than one test is done by that machine.*
- *For each test step, that step is executed by the machine assigned to the test that the test step is part of.*

Because you essentially introduced new constraints, you should:

1. Add `machine_id` to the `test` table;
2. add FK {`machine_id`} from `test` table to `machine` table;
3. add AK (unique) {`id, machine_id`} to the `test` table;
4. add FK {`test_id, machine_id`} from `test_step` table to `test` table;
5. you can drop now redundant FK {`test_id`} from `test_step` table to `test`.

This way, if the requirement changes again, you can simply drop these four DB objects.
It may be that the the whole test system may be expanded in the future, and the original requirement may still hold.

---

```
test {
    id
  , report_number
  , seq_number
  , test_state_id
  , customer_id
  , sample_rate
  , comment
  , create_time
  , start_time
  , end_time

  , machine_id -- added, point 1
}
PK  {id}
AK1 {report_number}
AK2 {id, machine_id} -- added, point 3

FK1 {customer_id}   REFERENCES customer   {id}
FK2 {test_state_id} REFERENCES test_state {id}
FK3 {machine_id}    REFERENCES machine    {id} -- added, point 2



machine {
    id
  , description
  , is_controlled
  , active
}
PK {id}


motion {
    id
  , description
  , plc_value
}
PK {id}



machine_motion {
    machine_id
  , motion_id
  , active
  }
PK  {machine_id, motion_id}

FK1 {machine_id} REFERENCES machine {id}
FK2 {motion_id}  REFERENCES motion  {id}



test_step {
    step_number
  , test_id
  , machine_id
  , motion_id
  , step_state_id
  , auto_continue
  , start_time
  , end_time
  }
PK  {test_id, step_number}

FK1 {machine_id, motion_id} REFERENCES machine_motion {machine_id, motion_id}
FK2 {test_id}               REFERENCES test           {id} -- redundant, pt 5
FK3 {step_state_id}         REFERENCES step_state     {id}

FK4 {test_id, machine_id} REFERENCES test {id, machine_id} -- added, pt 4
```

Comment: thank you. Actually after writing the post I ended up doing it almost this way, will definately add pt4 of your suggestions. Appreciate the feedback! Accepted the answer and would vote it up if I had the reputation ;-)